What is jq '.key["value"]'?
jq '.key["value"]' config.json is found in some of our bash scripts and when I tested it, it seems to be doing the same thing that jq '.key.value' config.json does.  So I am not sure why the latter (which I see everywhere else) is not used instead.  I tried to research this notation but found nothing.
Thanks in advance!

It's because the short form is only applicable if the field name (which can be any string) has no special characters (like dots, spaces, etc.). Also, if you the field to be accessed is not static (but evaluated), you need brackets to place the (sub-)filter into. Examples from the manual: .["foo::bar"] and .["foo.bar"] work while .foo::bar does not (and .foo.bar means something else).

Hi @pmf,
Thank you for your reply I understand that the double-quotes (") are needed in case there's a dot (.) in the field.  But not sure I understand why the brackets are there ([,])

Thanks for the reference to the topic in the manual.  I am checking it out now.

That's just another notation. .["key"] and ."key" do the same thing, but if "key" is not static (e.g. evaluated from a variable or another filter), you need the brackets. For example: .[$a] or .[.valueof.anotherkey], or .[ ["x","y","z"] | join("::") ].

Please don't spam tags

.key[ "value" ] and .key.value are equivalent.
These are specific uses of EXPR[ EXPR2 ] and EXPR.IDENT, two syntax for indexing. The differences in syntax impose the following differences in functionality:

EXPR.IDENT requires a hard-coded identifier.
EXPR[ EXPR2 ] accepts an expression which is evaluated at run-time.
EXPR[ EXPR2 ]'s EXPR2 isn't limited to return identifiers.
EXPR[ EXPR2 ]'s EXPR2 isn't limited to return strings.

While any uses of EXPR.IDENT can be converted to the EXPR[ EXPR2 ] syntax, the above means there's no way to convert the following uses of EXPR[ EXPR2 ] into the EXPR.IDENT syntax:

EXPR[ $key ] (The value of $key isn't known during development.)
EXPR[ "foo.bar" ] (foo.bar isn't an identifier.)
EXPR[ 0 ], to access an array element. (0 isn't an identifier.)

